# Question About Sampling White Noise

Tags: noise, sampling, homework

Assuming that we have a continuous signal $v(t)$

$$v(t) = \int_0^t g(u)\, \mathrm du\tag1$$

where $g(t)$ is white noise.Then take the derivative of it.

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\,\mathrm dt} v(t) = g(t)\tag2$$

Then sample $v(t)$ so that we get discrete-time model, and calculate the finite-difference instead of derivative

$$ v\left( (n+1) T_s\right) - v\left(nT_s\right) = \tilde g \left(nT_s\right) \cdot T_s \tag3$$

where $T_s$ is sampling interval.

I'm told that $\tilde g(nT_s)$ is the low-passed white noise, so how to prove it?

Comment: you seem to be mixing lower and upper case – so please confirm: Is your $V(t) = v(t)$?

Comment: by the way, your eq. $(2)$ is slightly wrong! $\frac{\mathrm d\,V}{\,\mathrm dt} (t) = G(t) - G(0)$.

Comment: in your last sentence, you mean $\tilde G$, not $G(nT_s)$, right?

Comment: By the way, this feels a lot like homework; so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: i'm not voting to close, but i'll be watching this question.  i hope to see it revised to make some sense.

Comment: Well...It's actually a small part of a signal model which should be solved by EFC. It seems that I paid much attention to the prrof of EFC and frazzled my brain...I consider about something like s(nTs) = s(t) *sigma δ（t-nTs）and its Fourier transform..Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *continuous-time* white noise process $\{X(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ is a hypothetical construct that we can treat (in the simplified versions that we use on dsp.SE) as a zero-mean wide-sense stationary process with autocorrelation function $K\delta(\tau)$ where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac delta. More strongly, all the random variables $X(t)$ are *mutually independent,* not just uncorrelated. Note that the power spectral density is $S_X(f) = K, \infty < f < \infty.$ Now, the stochastic integral 
$$Y(t) = \int_0^t X(u) \,\mathrm du$$ gives us a random *variable* whose mean we can find as
\begin{align}
E[Y(t)] &= E\left[\int_0^t X(u) \,\mathrm du\right]\\
&= \int_0^t E[X(u)] \,\mathrm du\\
&= 0 & \scriptstyle{E[X(u)] = 0~\text{as per definition of white noise}}
\end{align}
and whose variance is 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(Y(t)) &= E[(Y(t))^2]-\left(E[Y(t)]\right)^2\\
&= E[(Y(t))^2]\\
&= E\left[\int_0^t X(u) \,\mathrm du \int_0^t X(v) \,\mathrm dv\right]\\
&=  \int_0^t \int_0^t E[X(u)X(v)] \,\mathrm du   \,\mathrm dv\\
&= \int_0^t \left[\int_0^t K\delta(u-v) \,\mathrm du \right]  \,\mathrm dv\\
&= \int_0^t K  \,\mathrm dv\\
&= Kt \tag{1}
\end{align}
which shows us immediately that if we collect the $Y(t)$'s to form a random *process* $\{Y(t)\colon 0 \leq t < \infty\}$, then this process is *not* wide-sense stationary; its variance increases with time instead of being constant as is needed for wide-sense stationarity.

Turning to *sampling* from continuous-time processes to form a discrete-time process, note that it is *not* possible to sample a white noise process $\{X(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ to extract a single random variable, say $X(5)$, from it in part because white noise is an abstraction and in part because we (as engineers) must model reality and the reality is that an actual honest-to-goodness physical sampler doesn't sample instantaneously at $t$ but grabs a small chunk (say from $t-\varepsilon/2$ to $t+\varepsilon/2$) of whatever it is sampling, and it might be set up to report the *average value* $$ \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{t-\varepsilon/2}^{t+\varepsilon/2} x(u) \,\mathrm du$$ of the waveform as the sample value.  For deterministic signals, this is of little importance as long as $\varepsilon$ is small in comparison to how fast $x$ can change (for *small* $\varepsilon$, $\int_{t-\varepsilon/2}^{t+\varepsilon/2} x(u) \,\mathrm du \approx x(t)\cdot \varepsilon$ for continuous signals $x$) but for white noise, 
$$ \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{t-\varepsilon/2}^{t+\varepsilon/2} X(u) \,\mathrm du$$ is a zero-mean *random* variable with variance $\displaystyle\frac K\varepsilon \gg K$.

But the OP is not interested in sampling the white noise process but rather in looking at the random variables 
$$Z[n] = Y((n+1)T_s) - Y(nT_s) = \int_{nT_s}^{(n+1)T_s} X(u) \,\mathrm du$$ which can be easily shown to be independent zero-mean random variables of variance $KT_s$. That is,
$\{Z[n]\colon 0 \leq n < \infty\}$ is a *discrete-time* white noise process: a collection of *independent identically distributed* random variables with mean $0$ and variance $KT_s$.

Now consider the random process $\{\hat{X}(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ that is obtained by passing our original white noise process $\{X(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ through an ideal lowpass filter (unit gain in the passband) of bandwidth $W = \frac{1}{2T_s}$ so that the power spectral density $S_{\hat{X}}(f)$ is given by
$$S_{\hat{X}}(f) = S_X(f)\cdot \operatorname{rect}\left(\frac{f}{2W}\right) =\begin{cases}K, & -W < f < W,\\ 0, &\text{otherwise},\end{cases}$$
and autocorrelation function 
$$R_{\hat{X}}(\tau) = K(2W)\operatorname{sinc}(2W\tau) = KT_s\operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\tau}{T_s}\right).$$
*This* process $\{\hat{X}(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ is called a *low-pass* or *band-limited* white noise process (meaning that the power spectral density is constant within the frequency band of interest), and is *not* an abstraction as white noise (of infinite bandwidth and infinite power) is.  So, we *can* talk of sampling this process instantaneously if we like  --effectively assuming that the real-life sampler is returning exactly $\hat{X}(t)$ as the sample value, and the samples $\hat{X}(nT_s)$ all are zero-mean independent random variables with variance $KT_s$. Note that this is precisely the description of the $\{Z[n]\}$ process, that is, we can consider $\{Z[n]\}$ to be samples from a white noise process that has been low-pass filtered to bandwidth $\frac{1}{2T_s}$ and then sampled at $T_s$ second intervals (i.e. the Nyquist rate).

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Working with your definitions:

$$ v \left( \left( n + 1 \right) {T}_{s} \right) - v \left( n {T}_{s} \right) = \int_{0}^{ \left( n + 1 \right) {T}_{s} } g(u) du - \int_{0}^{ n {T}_{s} } g(u) du = \int_{ n {T}_{s} }^{ \left( n + 1 \right) {T}_{s} } g(u) du $$

So basically we have integration (Which is a Low Pass Filter) of White Noise over a Time Interval of $ {T}_{s} $.

Comment: Well...It's actually a small part of a signal model which should be solved by EFC. It seems that I paid much attention to the proof of EFC and frazzled my brain...I consider about something like s(nTs) = s(t) *sigma δ（t-nTs）and its Fourier transform..Thank you very much.