# Variance of a signal

Tags: noise, sampling, quantization, anti-aliasing-filter

How to calculate the variance of noise samples modeled as follows:

$n_a(t)$ is a
Gaussian zero-mean white noise process with (two-sided) power spectral density $\frac{N_0}{2}$. $n_a(t)$ is passed through an anti-alisasing filter to get the output $n_f(t)$. How to calculate the variance of the noise samples $n[j]$ in terms of $N_0$ and $B$, where $n[j]$=$n_f(jT_s)$ and $T_s$ is the sampling period.

Comment: What is $B{}{}{}$?

Comment: B is the Bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to calculate the variance of the noise samples $n[j]$ in terms of $N_0$ and $B$, where $n[j]$=$n_f(jT_s)$ and $T_s$ is the sampling period?

Do you know how to calculate the *variance* of the *process* 
$\{n_f(t) \colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$? 
No? Hint: it is the area under the power spectral density curve of $\{n_f(t)\colon -\infty < t < \infty\}$ provided that you are *not* using radian frequency but are using Hertzian frequency to express the PSD.  Well, if you know the process variance, then be assured that each *random variable* $n_f(t)$ in the process has the same variance as the process variance. A more interesting question for you to ponder might be: "Are $n[k]$ and $n[\ell]$ *independent* random variables or *correlated* random variables?" which will bring in that nuisance parameter $T_s$ into play.

Comment: Wouldn't the variance of process be infinite prior to sampling?

Comment: @Ben Sampling is of $n_f(t)$ which has finite variance, not of the white noise $n_a(t)$. See the question [Variance of White Gaussian noise](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/8629/235) for more details.

Comment: @Ben See also [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/56809/235).