# Kronecker delta instead of dirac delta as correlation function of white noise

Tags: noise, autocorrelation, gaussian, correlation

From my understanding, if you have a sample $x_{t_1},\dots,x_{t_n}$ of $X_{t_1},\dots,X_{t_n}$ which are iid $N(0,1)$, then $x_{t_1},\dots,x_{t_n}$ is a sample path of Gaussian white noise.

However, it is stated that the correlation function $c(s,t)$ of white noise is $\delta(s-t)$ where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. I understand that if $s\neq t$ then $c(s,t) = 0$. However, if $s=t$, you want $c(s-t)=1$. Why isn't the kronecker delta function used instead?

Comment: What is _your_ definition of the Kronecker delta function? Be sure to identify _all_ the symbols in what you write and tell us which are _real numbers_, which are _integers_, etc, Meanwhile, take a look at [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/56813/235).

Answer (score 3):

Dirac delta function has a continuous argument, but Kronecker delta function has a discrete argument.
Your example is a discrete signal so Kronecker delta is used.

Comment: But still, let's say that $X(t)$ is Gaussian white noise so that it is a continuous time stochastic process. If $c(s,t) = \delta(s-t)$, is the correlation function, does that mean that if $s=t$ then $c(s,t) \neq 1$ since $\delta(s-t)$ is the Dirac delta function?

Comment: @user1237300 Yes, Dirac's delta function is not a well defined function, but surely its value at 0 can't be 1.

Comment: So the discrete Gaussian white noise has no continuous time equivalent?

Comment: @user1237300 I'm not sure what did mean by equivalent, but continuous Gaussian white noise exist!